# Why OpenSSL tools can successfully verify a not signed file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, signing, pem

I have two files with the same content: msg.txt and msg2.txt. The msg.txt was signed, msg2.txt - was not signed. But I see both files passes the signature validation.

Why is it so? I thought if I sign a file, the signature should be attached somewhere to the file. But `hexdump` shows there is no difference between the files.

msg.txt

```
$ hexdump -C msg.txt
00000000 48 69 0a                     |Hi.|
00000003
```

msg2.txt

```
$ hexdump -C msg2.txt 
00000000 48 69 0a                     |Hi.|
00000003
```

Now every new file which contains "Hi" word only can be successfully verified. What if another user creates a file with a "Hi" word?!

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a self-signed PEM certificate-key pair

```
openssl req -x509 -sha512 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

2. Create files

```
$ echo "Hi" > msg.txt
$ echo "Hi" > msg2.txt
```

3. Sign msg.txt

```
$ openssl dgst -sha512 -sign key.pem -out /tmp/signature msg.txt
$ openssl base64 -in /tmp/signature -out signature
```

4. Verify msg.txt signature

```
$ openssl base64 -d -in signature -out /tmp/signature
$ openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
$ openssl dgst -sha512 -verify pubkey.pem -signature /tmp/signature msg.txt
Verified OK
```

5. Verify msg2.txt signature

```
$ openssl dgst -sha512 -verify pubkey.pem -signature /tmp/signature msg2.txt
Verified OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought if I sign a file, the signature should be attached somewhere to the file.

You explicitly put the signature into the separate file `/tmp/signature` which you later used when validating the signature - which explains why the signature was not part of the file.

And you did not sign a file but you signed the contents of a file - which explains why the signature can be applied to two separate files which have exactly the same contents.

Comment: How would you sign a file and attach the signature to the file? Then how to verify the signature having it attached to the file? I mean using openssl

Comment: @srgbnd: There is no generic "signature attached to a file" since there is no generic concept of "additional information attached to a file". Instead you would need some container which includes the original file contents and the related signature. An application which needs to access the contents would need to be able to understand the container format and extract the information from it. One container format build into openssl is S/MIME, see [smime](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-smime.html) for details.